# Android Kotlin - remove / reset RecyclerView OnScrollListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I load the RecyclerView and the ScrollListener inside a function

This is the code for setting the ScrollListener inside of it (I removed everything non necessary for the question):

```
    recyclerViewMemes.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

            val firstPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
            val lastPosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
            
            for (i in firstPosition..lastPosition) {
                if(adapterMemes.memes[i].pic.contains("_vid_")){ // ERROR HERE
                    Log.d(tagg, "bla")
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

When I try to reset the RecyclerView by calling the function again I get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on the line I commented with `ERROR HERE`. Which means the RecyclerView still gets triggered while resetting everything.

So how can I prevent this? Like removing / resetting the ScrollListener?

Comment: What do you mean by "reset the RecyclerView"? By calling which function again?

Comment: Maybe the one all that stuff is inside?What other functions did I mention??

Comment: Okay, so you answered my second question, but not my first.

Comment: Feeding it with another data. just resetting EVERYTHING including the ScrollListener

Comment: I appreciate that you are trying to be as minimal as possible with your code. However, you have left out important details that make it impossible to help. Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.

Comment: I also suggest that you use the debugger in Android Studio to step through your code to figure out what it is doing and why. you are getting an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
recyclerViewMemes.clearOnScrollListeners()
```

Before resetting